# Can somebody correct my proof? : if f is continuously differentiable, then f is differentiable.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

**Theorem:**

Let $U\subseteq \Bbb R^n$ be open.

If $f$ has continuous first partial derivatives in $U$ then $f$ is differentiable in $U$.

---

**Proof:**

Let's prove that if $f$ is differentiable at $a$ then $T(h)=Df(a).h$ ,where T(h) is total derivative.

Let's set $T(h)= (\alpha_1.h+\alpha_2.h+...+\alpha_n.h)=(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n).h $

Since $f$ has continuous derivatives, $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-T(h)}{\Vert h\Vert}=0 \tag 1$$ by the first order approximation theorem.

Set $h:=te_i$ for $t>0$

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-T(h)}{\Vert h\Vert}&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+te_i)-f(a)-\alpha_it}{t} \\
&=\frac{f(a+te_i)-f(a)}{t}-\alpha_i
\end{align}$$

$\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{f(a+te_i)-f(a)}{t}=\alpha_i$ by the equation (1)

We also need to check this limit for $t<0$

---

Do I prove the theorem? Is this proof enough? Do I have mistakes ? Please can one correct my proof? Thank you:)

Comment: Please define *continuous differentiability*.

Comment: Its definition is that f has partial derivatives and all partial derivatives are continuous. @GitGud

Comment: I imagine they mean "has continuous first partial derivatives". But what is the first order approximation theorem? Is $Df$ what I'm accustomed to seeing written $\nabla f$? Are the periods what I'm accustomed to seeing written as $\cdot$?

Comment: I used to know $Df$ in general. The line in The equation (1) is defined totally the theorem of first order approximation. @dfeuer

Comment: Yeah, I'd need a definition of continuously differentiable that didn't implicitly mean that it was differentiable.

Comment: B11b, it's okay that you're (apparently) not a native English speaker, but that means you have to be extra careful when explaining things. In an online mathematical forum, where being clear is more important than sounding good, it is best to use short sentences with simple structure and explain even the bits that seem obvious.

Comment: @dfeuer you editted as that $f$ has continuous partial derivatives. But my instructor wrote as mine in the notebook.

Comment: B11b, the theorem you're trying to prove here is *why* a function with continuous first partial derivatives on an open set is called continuously differentiable. Using that terminology to start off here is only going to confuse matters.

Comment: Hmm.. Okay! @dfeuer

Comment: @dfeuer by the way, yes, I speak English only for academic field. Everthing I have written is so clear and understandable. Only you make such a comment to me. It is interesting!

Comment: @GitGud Is the proof enough? What is your comment instead of the definiton of continuously differentiable ? Thank you.

Comment: B11b, it looks to me like your proof is starting with the assumption that $f$ is differentiable, and going on to prove that it has directional derivatives along the basis vectors, which I don't think is what you want to be doing at all.

Comment: Well, can you show me its proof correctly? Please.. @dfeuer

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n), y=(y_1,\ldots,y_n),$ write 
$$f(x)-f(y) =$$ $$ f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) - f(y_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) + f(y_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) - f(y_1,y_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n) + f(y_1,y_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n) - \ldots - f(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$$ and apply the mean value theorem multiple times.

You will find
$$
f(x)-f(y) - \nabla f(y)(x-y) = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\partial_if(z_i)-\partial_if(y)\right)(x_i-y_i).
$$
Do you see how to finish off the proof? Extra bonus: to show differentiability at an interior point $y$, it is actually enough to assume $n-1$ of the $\partial_i f$ exist in a ball around $y$ and are continuous at $y$, and that the $n$th partial just exists at $y$.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that it's also true that if the first partials exist in an open set and are continuous at a particular point, then the function is differentiable at that point?

Comment: Yes you are correct, that is what my proof above is leading you towards.

Comment: I misread what you wrote. What you said was already strictly more general than what I was thinking.